# PHP calculator using one input form

Tags: php

```
<?php
// current formula in input box
if (isset($_POST['txt'])) {
    $current_txt = $_POST['txt'];
}

if (isset($_POST['select1'])) {
    $message = "1";
}
if (isset($_POST['select2'])) {
    $message = "2";
}
if (isset($_POST['select3'])) {
    $message = "3";
}
if (isset($_POST['select4'])) {
    $message = "4";
}
if (isset($_POST['select5'])) {
    $message = "5";
}
if (isset($_POST['select6'])) {
    $message = "6";
}
if (isset($_POST['select7'])) {
    $message = "7";
}
if (isset($_POST['select8'])) {
    $message = "8";
}
if (isset($_POST['select9'])) {
    $message = "9";
}
if (isset($_POST['select0'])) {
    $message = "0";
}
if (isset($_POST['select+'])) {
    $message = "+";
}
if (isset($_POST['select-'])) {
    $message = "-";
}
if (isset($_POST['select/'])) {
    $message = "/";
}
if (isset($_POST['select*'])) {
    $message = "*";
}
if (isset($_POST['clear'])) {
    $message = "clear";
}
if (isset($_POST['calculate'])) {
    $message = "calc";
}

if ($message == "calc") {
    // Calculate using eval 
    $current_txt .= " = " . eval('return ' . $current_txt . ';');
} else {
    // Append input to formula
    $current_txt .= $message;
}

if ($message == "clear") {
    $current_txt = "";
}
?>

<div style="padding-left: 200px; margin-top: 100px">
    <form  method="post">
        Enter value:  <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php
        echo $current_txt;
        ?>" >
        <div style="padding-left: 105px"><br>

            <input type="submit" name="select1" value="1">
            <input type="submit" name="select2" value="2">
            <input type="submit" name="select3" value="3">
            <input type="submit" name="select4" value="4"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="select5" value="5">
            <input type="submit" name="select6" value="6">
            <input type="submit" name="select7" value="7">
            <input type="submit" name="select8" value="8"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="select9" value="9">
            <input type="submit" name="select0" value="0">
            <input type="submit" name="select+" value="+">
            <input type="submit" name="select-" value="-"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="select/" value="/">
            <input type="submit" name="select*" value="*">
            <input type="submit" name="clear" value="clear"> <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="calculate" value="calculate">

        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

when i do any operation it work. such as if i want to add two numbers like 5+6 = 11, but again if i want to add say a number 5 to the evaluated answer example 11+5 =16 so then its showing error that means only one time i can do operation again if i want to do operation to the evaluated answer its showing error, i'm trying to fix this issue but i'm not getting the way to do, so can any one let me know how to fix this issue.Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only two change you need to add

**1st** add previous number with result

```
if ($message == "calc") {
  $result = eval('return ' . $current_txt . ';');
  $current_txt = $current_txt.'='.$result;

 }
```

**2nd** get result value from string with explode function

```
if (isset($_POST['txt'])) {
    $current_txt = $_POST['txt'];
    $current_txt = end(explode("=",$current_txt));
}
```

Comment: @sameerpatil : copy paste this code : https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/s5n53zu2/ and run

Answer (score 0):

Update the(I have commneted your line) line:

```
 if ($message == "calc") {
    // Calculate using eval 
    // $current_txt .= " = " . eval('return ' . $current_txt . ';');
      $current_txt = eval('return ' . $current_txt . ';');
 }
```

hopefully it will solve your problem you:

Comment: Thank you , it really did solved my problem. Thanks alot

Comment: But I would like to implement ajax instead of page submit

Comment: i have been assigned to do it in php only.

Comment: Ok, as you wish...But implementing Ajax is also an optimized way.

Comment: ok i will try to do using that also, anyways thanks for guiding me.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($message == "calc") 
{
// Calculate using eval
//Add Below line for extact last expression calculation
$cal_arr=array_reverse(explode("=",$current_txt));
$current_txt .= " = " . eval('return ' . $cal_arr[0] . ';');   
}
```